# OBIEE Unions & Reporting Query

Tags: unions

I'm really hoping someone can help. I'm very new to OBIEE and currently trying to complete a report. I've done some research in to unions which has explained a lot but I'm really stuck on something.

I have a report I'm trying to complete where I have a list is sales representatives along with sales activity. However, once I throw in a column of 'sales volume' that has a 0 value, the sales representatives details disappear and all I'm left with are the details of sales representatives that have a numeric value, so those that have generated sales figures.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to where I may be going wrong?

Ideally I'd like to display a full list of sales representatives even when sales volume is 0. I'm using OBIEE 11G.

I have searched but not quite solved this one yet.

Id really appreciate any assistance on this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to an OBIEE Analysis report where you drag and drop columns, it sounds like you have a join issue behind the scenes in the Repository Database RPD. I would consult with whoever built your RPD.

It's hard to say without looking at the report, sql, and rpd, but this could be an simple join vs outer join issue. I hope this helps!